# React Native Image File to base64 / blob

Tags: image, react-native, base64, expo

This is my react native version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.63.4

can please someone help ? I tried so many things to change my file from mobile device to send it as base64 or blob to server
But none can change my file to base 64 or blob

here's how my console logh : path : look like
file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/b01f3aef-4b56-48d9-b7a2-e3424df0f054.jpg --------IMAGEURI

yes thats an image uri and I can show it up on my mobile screen just by calling

```
<Image uri={that file path...}/>

for (var i = 0 ; i < entriesImage.length ; i++){
        IdImage = [i][0]
        LabelImage = entriesImage[i][0]
        ImageUri = entriesImage[i][1].uri
        Notes = entriesImage[i][1].notes
        Latitude = entriesImage[i][1].location.latitude
        Longitude = entriesImage[i][1].location.longitude
        //DateImage = entriesImage[i][1].date
        DateImage = new Date()
        console.log(ImageUri,'--------IMAGEURI')
        objImage = {
            "surveyId": "3",
            "photo": entriesImage[i][1].uri,
            "photoId": [i][0],
            "label": entriesImage[i][0],
            "latitude": entriesImage[i][1].location.latitude,
            "longitude": entriesImage[i][1].location.longitude,
            "photoDate": DateImage,
            "notes": Notes
        }
        arrayImage.push(objImage)
    }
```

console.log(ImageUri,'--------IMAGEURI'), ImageUri as filepath I wanted to send to server

but still no luck on how to convert to to base64 or blob

I also tried expo image manipulator , also no luck , help please

Answer (score 0):

Create a `formData` and use it like this to send to server

Create a function

```
const CreateFormData = (filePath) => {
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append('file', {
    name: 'SampleImage.jpg',
    uri: filePath, // File path
    type: 'image/jpg',
  });
  return formdata;
};
```

Now use it like this

```
const response = CreateFormData("file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/b01f3aef-4b56-48d9-b7a2-e3424df0f054.jpg")
```

Now perform a POST request with this `response` formData in body

Comment: thanks for yrying to help but i dont think this is it, since , it only returns something like this 
FormData {
  "_parts": Array [
    Array [
      "file",
      Object {
        "name": "SmapleIMage.jpg",
        "type": "image.jpg",
        "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/e0c4c18c-eee2-4965-8b38-368eae22e98a.jpg",
      },
    ],
  ],
} .............. what i need is blob file so I can user can see that image anywhere else just convert jpg to 64 and 64 to jpg when user want to see it